# Run Zeppelin notebook from intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-zeppelin

I have installed Zeppelin notebook plugin on my IntelliJ. I also have my spark project running on IntelliJ (in scala). 
I have set the URL for Zeppelin notebook under language & Framework and then under Tools, clicked on New Zeppelin notebook. -> nothing happened

On clicking Run Zeppelin notebook, it says no notebook found.

How can I launch a new zeppelin notebook?

Am I missing something??